# how do I give my spinner same width as my EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-xml

I have my `EditText` width set to `wrap_content`

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password_retype"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/passwordRetype"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and below it I have my spinner as below:

```
   <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/states_options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/send"
            android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

I came from iOS development and there we have something called "equal width", is there a way on android that enables me to set the width of my spinner exactly the same as my edit text?

Comment: Give width to parent layout, use Match Parent attribute, if no parent is available create one

Comment: is it in 1 layout?

Comment: please tell what is the parent layout and if this is in one layout

Comment: The parent layout is linear layout, but I will create new one and set it there, thanks for all your replies, I got the idea of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like setting "Trailing & Leading Space" in iOS, in Android set same "Layout Margin Left and Right" for both EditText and Spinner. It might solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it around a `LinearLayout` and match it there for example like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_password_retype"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/passwordRetype"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/states_options"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/send"
            android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your parent width, you can achieve the thing like this.  Change the spinner width to match_parent.   Hope this will solve the issue.

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reg_password_retype"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/passwordRetype"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/states_options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/send"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Through code do this -

findView first

```
    EditText edt=(EditText)findviewById(R.id.reg_password_retype);
    Spinner spinner (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.states_options);
   getWindow().getDecorView().getViewTreeObserver()
.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          @Override
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
            LayoutParam lp=spinner.getlayoutParam();
           lp.width=edt.getWidth();
    sippner.setLayoutParam(lp);
            getWindow().getDecorView()
.getViewTreeObserver()
.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
          }
        });
```